# Windows 10 scaling messes with drawing dimensions

Tags: java, javafx, windows-10

I have an application that displays a fullscreen `AnchorPane` containing an `ImageView` with its fit height/width set to the size of the pane to make the image it contains fullscreen iself.

I've just upgraded my setup to a 3840x2160 display, which has me using Windows 10 built-in scaling factor for comfort. However, this scaling now messes with the application.

I'm setting the pane dimension using this code, which can also cycle through multiple monitors.

```
GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] monitors = e.getScreenDevices();

if ((full.isShowing() && monitors.length > 1) || monitor < 0) {
   monitor = (monitor + 1) % monitors.length;
   GraphicsDevice device = monitors[monitor];
   Rectangle bounds = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();

   full.setX(bounds.x);
   full.setY(bounds.y);
   full.setWidth(bounds.width);
   full.setHeight(bounds.height);
}
```

The pane dimension reports naturally at 3840x2160. However, Windows apply its scaling to the pane and it ends up at an incorrect dimension. My possible fix for this problem are as follow:

1. Find a way to retrieve the scaling factor and divide the resolution to fit the screen correctly. This is not ideal: the display resolution will be lower than the resolution of the screen.
2. Find a way to bypass the scaling, effectively telling Windows to not scale the pane, although scaling the rest of the UI is fine.
3. Anything else?

EDIT: After running a test with `setFullScreen` on the stage. I've found out this solution does not completely solve the issue. What happens is exactly what I describe in fix #1: The application does appear fullscreen, however this image is displayed at an inferior resolution, only to be upscaled by windows scaling.

EDIT(2): Here's a code sample that highlights the issue

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      Parent root = new AnchorPane();        
      Scene scene = new Scene(root);

      Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
      System.out.println("Bounds:" + bounds);
      stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
      stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
      stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
      stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

      stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

On my 3840x2160 screen, the bounds report `Bounds:Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1400.0, width=2560.0, height=1440.0]` The pane is visually of the right dimension, but the pane's resolution is lower (windows upscaling at work). Worse the pane does not even show at the expected position of (0, 0) but at roughly (970, -340)... I suppose the position is also affected by the scaling in a very weird way.

Calling `stage.setFullScreen(true)` moves the pane at the correct position but the pane resolution is still lower than desired. (Also, there is the problem of the full screen exit hint that cannot be disabled, but that's a different matter).

Comment: Instead of computing the Stage size from a GraphicsConfiguration, consider [maximizing](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMaximized%28boolean%29) or [fullscreening](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen%28boolean%29) your Stage.

Comment: I don't remember what had caused me to avoid setFullScreen, I'll give it a try. I believe there is a notification when you do so that could not be disabled.

Comment: Did some tests, see edit of the question.

Comment: Can you show the code that builds the Stage, including the AnchorPane and ImageView?

Comment: Side note: JavaFX has the [`Screen`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html) class.

Comment: I've added details with reproductible steps.